# Cannot change state of one item across multiple inputs in a form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that takes a couple of inputs. To store their states I created an object which works fine for all inputs except the date one.

```
// Input handler
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    applicant: '',
    position: '',
    startSalary: '',
    date: null,
    months: 0,
    increase: 0,
    interval: "",
    method: "",
});

const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    console.log(values)
};


..

{/* Months Period */}
<div className="flex">
    <div className="input-wrapper flex justify-between w-full items-center">
        <FormControl sx={{ width: '95%', marginRight: '20px' }}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-amount">Months</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            id="outlined-adornment-amount"
            value={values.months}
            onChange={handleChange('months')}
            startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">n</InputAdornment>}
            label="Months"
            type="number"
          />
        </FormControl>
    </div>
</div>

{/* Date Picker */}
<div className="input-wrapper flex justify-between items-center">
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Start Date"
        value={values.date}
        onChange={handleChange('date')}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
</div>
..
```

When I change the date on the client side it returns [image]

However, **this works** isolated for the datepicker:

```
...
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

<div className="input-wrapper flex justify-between items-center">
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Start Date"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing above code, seems like `DatePicker` isn't returning you an event object.

Simply check, by doing a console.log in your handleChange method.
Also,you can add if checks to manage such cases.

```
const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    if(prop === 'date') {   
      setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event});
    } else {
       setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    }
    console.log(values)
};
```

PS: Answering to your comment,

This is happening because `DatePicker` is doing the hard work to extract `value` from `event` object.

It is overriding the default `onChange` event if `input`

This is demo of how it might be happening:

```
const DatePicker = (props) => {
const {onChange = ()=> {}} = props;

const handleChange = (event)=> {
    const value = event.target.value;

    onChange(value); // this value you are receiving.

} 

return <input type="date" onChange={handleChange} />


}
```

Comment: ye it really seems it doesnt. This is probably what the inserted error is telling, since on the client side nothing happens with the value when I select a new date from the pop-up. How to deal with this?

Comment: @Jonas simply add a if check in your handle change. Let me update my answer

Comment: that works, thanks! But how? As I understand the code is that we still pass `event` as new value for that prop, but since DatePicker isn't returning an event how can we pass it as new value?

Comment: @Jonas I've updated my answer. To answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

DatePicker returns date not an event. You can handle it like this

```
const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    if(prop === 'date') {
      return setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event });
    }
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

DatePicker will provide you the array of dates so you can store the dates using the following method:-

```js
const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    if (prop === date){
        setValues({...values, [prop]: moment(event[0])})
    }else {
        setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    }
    console.log(values)
};
```

Moment is the npm package used for changing the date from iso string to normal form and you can also format the dates using this package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment